# input type="number" is not able to delete/clear on selecting the number in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have validation to accept the min and max value for an input type="number" field. Once I entered some input it is working according to the max and min value. What is my problem is I could not able to clear/delete an entered value in the number field. In textbox field, it is allowing to clear the value by using backspace and selecting the number and type new number. why number field is not working in that scenario. how to make it clear/delete the number in the number field.

```
  <input type="number" name="WorkingDaysPA" id="WorkingDaysPA"
             min="1" max="366" style="text-align: right"

             onkeypress="if(this.value.length==3) return false;return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"
         />

<input type="text" maxlength="3" min="1" max="366">
```

Here My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MariNithya/fpd2y4f4/

Comment: fiddle link broken.

Comment: now, fiddle is working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On focus out event, I am assiging null as value;

Hope this helps

```js
document.getElementById("validateNums").addEventListener("focusout", inputOutOfFocus);
function inputOutOfFocus() {
 document.getElementById("validateNums").value = null;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" maxlength="3" min="1" max="366" id="validateNums">
```

Comment: this will work for input type="text". without this also textbox clear the value on selecting value and type new value. But my need is for input type="number"

Comment: in chrome, I can clear the value which is already entered on selecting the number  for input type="number" But , in Firefox and IE is not working

Comment: what version of firefox are u using? I tested it in firefox version 55 and it works ; By default it wont; but above code makes it work; I dont have IE ; so cant comment on that;

Comment: Firefox 57.0. the above code is working for both number and text type ?

Comment: yes, it is working for me also. But max value validation is not  working when I type the number manually without using arrow keys.

Comment: I thought your qn was about clearing the input box; do u want help in max validation as well?

And yes, in firefox 55, both types (number,text) work

Comment: yes, my need is to clear input. Input text and number is working for me in Firefox as well IE. Now, I want to restrict to type the number with in min and max value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pbqrws5u/2/ ; this resolves max limit issue; works in both firefox and chrome; not sure of IE. cheers

Comment: yes, got it. Working.. This answer is helped for me

Answer (score 0):

to clear the text field we use document.getElementById("exampleId").textContent = "";
whereas to clear number field use document.getElementById("exampleId").value =null ;

hope this solves your problem.